# Labeling derivatives of functions from a graph

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I have a question about derivatives and identifying them on a graph. I came across a problem that looks like this:

[The figure shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRHUr.png) graphs of f, f-prime, f-prime-prime, and f-pime-prime-prime. Identify each curve. Justify your answers.

I feel like f is B. F-prime is C. F-prime-prime is A. And f-prime-prime-prime is D since that's the only one left. Justifying my answers is another story. I know what f-prime-prime looks like, and I know what f-prime looks like, so I'm assuming B is f since it would be a good fit, but I don't know how to justify the relationship between the double derivative and the triple derivative.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

A, B, C, and D look like the graphs of linear, quadratic, cubic, and quartic polynomials respectively.  Think about this and about what happens to the degree of a polynomial when you take its derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you're intended to solve this problem using the two facts:

1) If a function is strictly increasing over an interval, then its derivative is positive over that interval.

2) If a function is strictly decreasing over an interval, then its derivative is negative over that interval.

Also, keep in mind that a higher order derivative is a derivative. E.g., $f''$ is the derivative of $f'$ and $f'''$ is the derivative of $f''$.

If you start with $B$ as the graph of $f$, then $C$ would be a reasonable choice for the graph of $f'$. At least, things will fall in line with 1) and 2).

But if  $C$ is the graph of $f'$, then the graph of $f''=(f')'$ must be positive everywhere by 1) above. So it can't be $A$. In fact, it can't be any of the remaining graphs (so, note $B$ "comes after" $C$).

Also, your reasoning at the end is wrong. You can't say $D$ is the graph of $f'''$ just because it's the only one left. In fact, look at $A$: it's a straight line, and so its derivative is constant. If you say $A$ is the graph of $f''$, then $D$ can't be the graph of $f'''=(f'')'$.

Upon reconsidering things, you might note that $D$ could be the graph of $f$.

In fact, note that $D$ cannot be the graph of the derivative of any of the other functions:  we've seen why for $A$. For the graphs $B$ and $C$, note their derivatives at $x=0$ are $0$ (look at tangent lines), while $D$  has a $y$-value of $-3$ at $x=0$  (of course other arguments could be used here using 1) and 2)).

So, indeed, $D$ is the graph of $f$.

Next in line, $f'$, would have graph either $C$ or $A$, since only these fall in line with 1) and 2) ($D$ is decreasing for $x<0$ and increasing for $x>0$). 
It can't be $A$ since there would be no choice for $f''$ (you could also argue more rigorously by looking at how fast the slopes
of tangent lines to $D$ change).

So the graph of $f$ is $D$ and the graph of $f'$ is $C$.  The rest is easy (don't forget to justify the rest by verifying 1) and 2) above)...

Comment: I think my method "defeats the spirit of the problem" as I like to say.